# Where to find CPANEL object file Path on Localhost and Live server

Tags: php, cpanel, cpanel-uapi

sorry if my question might sound silly. I am trying to create an email address with Cpanel UAPI with LiveAPI.php but I seem to be lost on some codes.

The documentation to create email address is gotten from https://api.docs.cpanel.net/openapi/cpanel/operation/add_pop/

I use this code according to the docs

```
<?php
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Instructions:
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 1) cd /usr/local/cpanel/base/frontend/paper_lantern
// 2) mkdir api_examples
// 3) cd api_examples
// 4) create a file Email_add_pop.live.php and put this code into that file.
// 5) In your browser login to a cPanel account.
// 6) Manually change the url from: .../frontend/paper_lantern/
//    to .../frontend/paper_lantern/api_examples/Email_add_pop.live.php
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Instantiate the CPANEL object.
require_once "/usr/local/cpanel/php/cpanel.php";

// Print the header
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// Connect to cPanel - only do this once.
$cpanel = new CPANEL();

// Call the API
$response = $cpanel->uapi(
    'Email',
    'add_pop',
    array (
        'email' => 'zomba',
        'password' => '123456luggage',
        'domain' => 'example.com',
        'quota' => 'unlimited',
        'send_welcome_email' => '1',
        'skip_update_db' => '0',
    )
);

// Handle the response
if ($response['cpanelresult']['result']['status']) {
    $data = $response['cpanelresult']['result']['data'];
    // Do something with the $data
    // So you can see the data shape we print it here.
    print to_json($data);
}
else {
    // Report errors:
    print to_json($response['cpanelresult']['result']['errors']);
}

// Disconnect from cPanel - only do this once.
$cpanel->end();

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Helper function to convert a PHP value to html printable json
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function to_json($data) {
    return json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

WHAT I DO NOT UNDERSTAND IS FROM

HERE

```
<?php
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Instructions:
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 1) cd /usr/local/cpanel/base/frontend/paper_lantern
// 2) mkdir api_examples
// 3) cd api_examples
// 4) create a file Email_add_pop.live.php and put this code into that file.
// 5) In your browser login to a cPanel account.
// 6) Manually change the url from: .../frontend/paper_lantern/
//    to .../frontend/paper_lantern/api_examples/Email_add_pop.live.php
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Instantiate the CPANEL object.
require_once "/usr/local/cpanel/php/cpanel.php";
?>
```

STOPS HERE.

WHERE DO I FIND

```
require_once "/usr/local/cpanel/php/cpanel.php";
```

I DONT UNDERSTAND THAT LINE.

I saw this forum post https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/using-cpanel-uapi-in-from-my-php.672337/ that had my exact issues, but after reading it, I got more confused, following the links for more help, the resulting page is depreciated.

I checked Stackoverflow cpanel-uapi tag here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpanel-uapi no answer

Please who has an idea on what I need to learn or install or set properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the api here, on cPanel github:
https://github.com/CpanelInc/publicapi-php

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).